# What is the best way to design a system, flowchart or UML?

Tags: oop, uml, system, flowchart

I've been assigned a task to design a system and they prefer flow chart. But from my study around, it's preferred to design using UML concepts. Now I am a bit confused.

Comment: If "they" prefer a flowchart, give them a flowchart! They did not ask you what is the best way, they asked you for a flowchart..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with **Use-Case** Diagrams first followed by **Sequence** Diagrams. They are pretty easy to start with.